# Collect/Filter all the items till conditon is met in Kotlin list

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a list/sequence of items for example `[a_0, a_1, a_3, a_4,...,a_n]`

I have a predicate `(a) -> Boolean` where `a_i` is the first element at i_th position for which the predicate returns true. **Remember** index `i` is **NOT** known upfront.

Is there any oneliner solution to get the sublist `[a_0, a_1, a_3,...,a_i]` using single operator from stdlib or collection of operators from stdlib.

I don't want to maintain the variable which checks if we have hit the first element satisfying the condition or not as that doesn't look good or functional or create a function custom function for that

TLDR

I want a operator(or set of operators) from stdlib which behaves like as follow `listOf(1, 2, 3,...n).takeTill { i >= calculateIndex() }` which should return `[1, 2, 3]` when `calculateIndex()` returns `3`

Comment: `takeWhile()` is almost what you are looking for, but it skips the last item. If you can easily change the condition to include this single item, then it should be enough for you. For example: `takeWhile { i <= calculateIndex() }`. But if you can't change the condition like this, then I guess we need a new operator.

Comment: No, I can't change the condition as you have mentioned. I am also aware of `takeWhile()` but skipping the last element is a blocker for me. I also want to use this operator on sequence so that I can't reiterate the sequence again.

You are correct that currently, Kotlin doesn't have this operator in its stdlib

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Kotlin extension on all Lists to perform the functionality you're looking for

```
fun <T> List<T>.takeTill(condition: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()
    for ((i, value) in withIndex()) {
        result.add(value)
        if (condition(value)) {
            break
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

usage matches your request: `listOf(1, 2, 3,...n).takeTill { i >= 3 }`

Comment: I am not able to find the `takeTill` operator even in `kotlin` 1.9 which `kotlin` stdlib you are using?

Although this is exactly I am looking

Comment: You can add the code snippet to your project to gain the "takeTill" extension. I also wrote this answer before I saw your edit that you know the index beforehand.

Comment: hmmm.. it seems like there is no pre-built operator for this even to me this seems like a very trivial case

No index is not know upfront I have edited once more to add NOT to it

Comment: Then adding the code I gave will give what you wanted. Copies the list up to and including the item that triggers the condition. And with trailing closures you can use it as `takeTill {}`

Comment: yes, I was aware that I can write my own extension function but I was hoping to use builtin operators. BTW you can improve your code by adding `inline` in your method

Comment: Spoke so soon :( . Actually, I have a sequence and this code directly will not work on the sequence

Comment: @AndroidEngineX: You may want to use built in operators, but as you've found, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You have both

- `.take(n: Int)` like `.take(3)` which simply returns first n elements
- `.takeWhile(predicate: (T) -> Boolean)` which return first elements until condition would be violated. Like `.takeWhile { it.startsWith("a") }`

Comment: I can't use `take(3)` as that is hardcoding the index in my question I never said that I knew the index.

Also `takeWhile { it.startsWith("a") }` will not work as I have to also take starting elements which doesn't qualify the predicate

Comment: I have also updated the question to avoid these answers. You can also delete your answer or update the answer